# Does contemporary art embody the desacralisation of western culture?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, aesthetics

It's noticeable that all the great artistic traditions embody their religious worldviews: Hindu temples, Christian churches, Greek statues of gods and heroes, Egyptian sarcophagi, etc.

However, modern/contemporary art seems to lack this entirely. If it refers to it, it's mostly in the mode of rejection and rebellion, for example, Serrano's [Piss Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piss_Christ). There are some pieces that reflect on an ambiguous transcendentalism; Rothko's large muted canvases come to mind.

Is this a reflection that for the art-making and art-appreciating classes in the West that religion has no ontological weight? That their worldview is materialistic and focused on the present rather than pointing to some spiritual realm?

Comment: "great artistic traditions embody their religious worldviews" we don't know this but we do know that in the past art aligned with the dominant religion often gets financial backing, good press and curatorship.  Indeed this editorial structure has crumbled in the last couple of centuries.  Perhaps there always were profound expressions unaligned with the dominant religion of the place and time that was suppressed out of history. The Buddhas of Bamiyan come to mind.

Comment: What does a tradition consist of? At what point does the absence of religious iconography, current or antiquated, become pertinent? For instance, what about the general absence of iconography from the impressionists on to the cubists?

Comment: There's also the possibility that it reflects a shift in the organization of "religion" and its relationship to the culture-at-large. That is, perhaps the current iconography can suggest that we are entering a mode where the dominant manifestation of the sacred is a sort of material and rebellious novo-paganism.

Comment: @obelia: What do you mean? The Buddhas were presumably sculpted because they were aligned with the most pervasive religous expression at the time. That we in the West weren't aware of them does not mean that they weren't unknown to the locals there *now*. Why the Taliban destroyed them, I do not know. Although Islam is against 'idols', doesn't mean it is neccessary to tear them down. Intention is important.  What is surprising to me is how easily what was once a dominant expression falls out of favour and becomes almost invisible.

Comment: @Beaudrap: That's a very short period of time. Why stop at the cubists, its still here with us. Picasso was inspired by [Poincare](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/blog/2012/jul/17/henri-poincare-einstein-picasso) of all people towards Cubism. Does one have to define a tradition? As a mathematician, I'm sure you're aware of the traditions in your own field.

Comment: @wmjbyatt: I can kind of agree with that.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I mention the Buddhas of Bamiyan as an example of an expression suppressed (actually destroyed) by the dominant religion of the place/time, suggesting that the surviving artistic artefacts we have might be biased towards the "winning" religion.

Comment: Most of the artistic movements of the 19th and early 20th centuries were agnostic: think impressionism, cubism, primitivism, surrealism, and early abstract work. It wasn't until Warhol that art took on that jaded, cynical, socially-pointed aspect and became (in places) overtly anti-religious.